# Accessing Documentation XML for Blazor.Shared Models for API Docs

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, blazor, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a Blazor "Full stack" (ASP.NET Core Hosted) solution, which includes three projects by default: `Blazor.Client`, `Blazor.Server`, and `Blazor.Shared`. I have some API controllers on Blazor.Server, and some of those Controllers use Models that live in Blazor.Shared. This is how the solution is set up by default (with the example WeatherForecast API). I have followed this same model for my own APIs.

I'm now trying to add Swagger documentation to my project, and I can't figure out how to add XML documentation for the Models that live in `Blazor.Shared`. As a result, I'm only getting descriptions for the Controllers, and not for the Models they use. Specifically, I'm trying to add both xml documentation files in `Startup.cs`:

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyProject", Version = "v1" });
            options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Blazor.Server.Doc.xml"));
            options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Blazor.Shared.Doc.xml"));
        });
```

However, the second `IncludeXmlComments` line here results in an exception because `System.AppContext.BaseDirectory` gives me the path to `Blazor.Server`'s `bin`. The Shared xml docs live in a separate `bin` generated in the `Blazor.Shared` project.

I've been searching around but it sounds like there's not a supported way to get the path from one project to another in net core, so I'm not sure exactly what to do about this. Can I get the path to the `Blazor.Shared` bin? Or is there a different way I should be going about this? Ultimately: **How do I access documentation xml for Blazor.Shared classes from Startup.cs in Blazor.Server?**

Comment: Blazor.Shared.xml should be copied to the base directory on build .did you check the file exists in Blazor.Shared/bin/debug/netstandard2.0 ? And the name should be Blazor.Shared.xml, why did you add .Doc ?

Comment: What does "this doesn't work" mean?  When a file is Not Found you will get an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Shared xml docs live in a separate bin

Is true, but they are normally copied to the Server bin folder on build.

I'm looking at a similar project right now and 'it just works'.

Comment: This led me in the right direction to find the solution.I had an explicit xml documentation path defined in each project file (`<DocumentationFile>bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\$(AssemblyName).Doc.xml</DocumentationFile>`). That did not work. When I replaced this line with `<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>` in both projects, it started working.